# What is this component and what is its use?

Tags: components, identification, tv

I found this in CRT TV on the CRT tube driver PCB.

[image]

[image]

What are they and what is their schematic symbol?

Comment: An overvoltage spark gap perhaps?

Comment: Was is directly connected to the pins on the CRT?  If yes its almost certainly a spark gap.

Comment: What is that cloudy-white plastic material around it?  Is it rubbery, flimsy, solid, etc..

Comment: @Funkyguy it is solid, not at all rubbery.

Comment: IS there an actual gap between the wires in side the part labelled with "air gap" from the pictures it looks like a nick in the wires but there could be a small gap in there too.

Comment: @placeholder There IS a gap there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, the part shown in the photograph is a spark gap. [This page](http://www.electricstuff.co.uk/sparkgaps.html) lists several such spark gaps and similar / related parts.

Below is an inert-gas filled spark gap, closest in functionality to the part in the question, yet safer due to being glass encapsulated:

[image: SparkGap]

A more common modern version of this device is offered by [Littelfuse](http://www.littelfuse.com/data/en/data_sheets/littelfuse-src_gdt_cg-cg2.pdf) and others, and comes in several different packages:

[image: Littelfuse Spark Gap]

The through-hole versions are [available on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/GAS-DISCHARGE-TUBE-SPARK-GAP-LITTELFUSE-CG21000L-10A-1KV-/251018342373) for around $1 to $2 in single units, if you would like to experiment with one.

---

Various schematic symbols for spark gaps are documented [on WikiMedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Spark_gap_schematic.png):

[image: Spark Gap schematic symbols]

Of these, symbol #2 is most commonly supported in the schematic software I have used.

Comment: To me, #1 is a surge arrester (i.e. metal oxide varistor.) #4 is a generic symbol for variable resistance, i.e. a temperature measuring thermistor. I would use #2 for a spark gap.

Comment: For info, the Littelfuse style gas-filled spark-gaps are used extensively in telecomms for lightning protection. In fact, give or take every UK phone line has one across the end where it enters the telephone exchange.