# What is this component on circuit schematics?

Tags: power-supply, power, components, identification, schematics

[image]

It's a resistor like coloured 2 pin component from a power supply board of a home theatre, with a glass-transparent aspect. I'm a hobbyist and not into complex circuit till now...  looking for an answer online but couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Enter the part number YP-501M into Google. There are photos.  Do they match your part?

Comment: Spark gap perhaps?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125237/what-does-this-symbol-in-the-schematic-represent/125238

Answer (score 2):

[image: Is this what you mean?]

Is this what you mean?

Google says YP-501M is surge absorber. You can read from the link below for reference.
http://www.mmc.co.jp/adv/dev/english/document/surge_absober/surgeabsober04.html

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everybody, turns out it is a DIAC, Diode for alternating current. 
That's why it is so hard to test on a multimeter, its only works after a specific voltage break point.

Comment: I am curious about the mismatch between the function and the part number. How did you determine it was a DIAC?

Comment: No, it isn't a DIAC, although it has similar electrical characteristics.

Comment: This is not a DIAC. It's a spark gap.

Comment: Looks like spark gaps and DIACS did behave as the same when tested. So, in fact it is not a DIAC, i agree.  Until now I had not seen spark gaps on circuits. 
I assume DIAC because of the infinte resistance on multimeter and similarity of the symbols. I think the question is pretty much answered, i'm after the new part now. Thx

Answer (score -4):

those Two Diodes(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode) are impacting each other.

Comment: This is not a very helpful answer, please improve it.

Comment: This answer is not correct.