# Spark gap schematic symbol help

Tags: components, symbol

I disassembled a Sharp 42" LCD TV power supply board and discovered 3 glass Spark Gap components (Gas Discharge Tube/Surge Absorbers). I haven't worked with them before and I'm curious about the schematic symbols silkscreened on the PCB. Based on the component specs (there are 2 types here: DA38-452MT, DSPL-301N, from Mitsubishi MMC) I presume the symbols refer to high voltage and low voltage. For the high voltage symbol, are we really looking at thunder clouds suggestive of lightning strike surges?

From Sharp Aquos LC-42D69U LCD TV service manual

SG801 = Spark Gap DA38-452MT

SG802 = Spark Gap DSPL-301N

[image: PCB silkscreen]

[image: power board]

Comment: the cloud symbol could mean "gas filled"

Comment: remotely related question about spark gap: [What does this symbol in the schematic represent?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/125237/7036)