# Need help Identifying a resistor like component with orange and black bands

Tags: resistors, diodes, identification, components, telephone

This component was on a telephone that was mistakingly connected to the mains rather than the phone line. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Probably not a zero-ohm resistor, as I've never seen one in a glass package.  Could be a bi-directional transient absorber, basically a back-to-back zener diode.

Comment: Looks like a diode.

Comment: Not a diode....black line wouldn't be in the center.   Agree its probably a transorb

Comment: @AnalogKidThanks! Can it be replaced with a normal Zener diode?

Comment: Looks eerily similar to some spark gap's I've seen in some SMPS.

Comment: Mistakenly connected to mains. Oh my.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks very similar to some spark gaps I've seen used on switch mode power supplies.

There is a post on this forum that confirms this:
[Spark gap schematic symbol help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442370/spark-gap-schematic-symbol-help)

Comment: Interesting, they look almost identical. So it's some kind of varistor. Thanks for the help!