# What is this symbol: semicircles facing each other?

Tags: schematics, symbol

What does this symbol represent?

[image: Mystery symbol]

It was found on the circuit diagram for a `TDS973A` [a board for which this was the only information I was able to find online](https://www.triangledigital.org.uk/man9092/ch6tds973.htm).

[image: Schematic containing symbol]

Comment: closing A, C, and D seems to be the nuclear option

Comment: @dlatikay I wonder if there's a mistake in the schematic somewhere around D. It seems to connect "peripheral +12V" to 5V, which sounds undesirable at best.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

These are "solder links" and could look like:

[image]

Note how the top right one looks the most similar to the symbol from the schematic.

These are copper shapes on a PCB.

If you don't do anything these structures will be an "open" so they make no connection.

But using a soldering iron and some solder it is easy to apply some solder and **make** that connection.

This can be used to connect / disconnect certain parts of a circuit on a PCB and so set certain options, for example to feed a certain voltage to a line (or not).

Comment: Note, symbols with [arrows instead of shapes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125237/what-does-this-symbol-in-the-schematic-represent/125238) are not solder-bridge points, but a purpose-built gap to allow arcing under certain controlled circumstances. Solder-bridge points are *not* designed for that.

Answer (score 43):

Those are solder-bridge points and the circuit symbol accurately represents the shape of the PCB pads.

[image]

*Figure 1. Options J1, J2 and J4 have been bridged. Option J3 has been left open. Source: [PCB Libraries](https://www.pcblibraries.com/forum/footprint-for-solderable-jumper_topic2089.html).*